# Are there any difference between 'Are you a native Chinese?' and 'Are you native Chinese?"

Tags: meaning, difference, articles

For the following sentences, are they same in meaning?

> 1: Are you a native Chinese?
>
> 2: Are you native Chinese?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, when the name is ended with "-ese" like *Chinese* and *Japanese*, it's quite rude to use it as a noun, I prefer *Chinese person* or *Chinese people*.

*You* can be plural or singular(Some dialects use *y'all* for the plural form). I guess that puts you in a confusion. The former uses *you* as a singular pronoun, and the latter uses *you* as plural pronoun.

> **Are you a native Chinese?** *is a question for a second person.*
>
> **Are you native Chinese?** *is a question for second person**s**. It may refer to a group of people*

Answer (score 2):

Both sentences are different in meaning.

The word Chinese is a singular noun in the former and a plural noun in the latter,

The word native is an adjective modifying the Chinese in these sentences. So these sentences mean:

Are you a native Chinese? = Are you a native of China?

Are you native Chinese? = Are you natives of China?